# Can I get a dweller back after banishing them?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I accidentally banished my best dweller. Is there any way that I can get him back, or is he lost forever?

Comment: Your dweller is going to be lost in the wastelands, never to be seen again

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you cannot. On rare occasions I've heard they can come back as someone wanting the enter the vault but that's just a rumor. So sorry there is no way to get them back.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get a dweller back when banished but when a dweller is banished all his/her stuff comes back to you if not your game is probably bugged.